# advise on using parallel computing on different levels

Tags: r, parallel-processing

We know that it is better to use parallel computing for longer tasks than shorter tasks, in order to save OS time when switching many small tasks. I am looking for your comments and advise on the following scenario. I got 6 task I can parallel, each of them has a small task that can also be paralleled. Let's say I have 64 cores I can use.

Would it be prudent to use parallel for the 6 larger tasks, and then to parallel again within each task?

Comment: Given that you have 64 cores, you won't be able to parallelize on the highest level since most of them would be waiting. You're "stuck" with parallelizing the lower level. Without some reproducible code, that's probably all the advice we can give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered your own question. If the individual tasks are short, the overhead of parallelisation will cause the total calculation time to go up in stead of down. This does not really change when having this kind of hierarchy of parallel jobs. I would think the overhead is even bigger as the information has to be passed down form the smallest jobs, via the intermediate jobs to the top-level. If your smallest tasks do not take a significant amount of time, say at least a few seconds, parallelisation is not going help.